# Fullcalendar get position or get get resource

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, fullcalendar

I'm trying to build a fullcalendar with vertical resources [(like this one)](http://plnkr.co/edit/8d16J15gKhE2IKCATspZ?p=preview). 
[This is sean kennerys fork](https://github.com/seankenny/fullcalendar)

I've already achieved all working functionality except getting the resource ID from the event drop.

When I drop a event I get the array of resources i've on that view (resourceDay view)

[image]

[image]
In the header i've the id (in this example its 219) in the table header class

[image]
(right mouse click -> open in new tab for bigger version)

The first problem I've is that the drop in this plugin doesn't give me a resource ID back.
The second problem is I don't know how I can get the row and then get the id from the header

My drop function:

```
drop: function(date, allDay) { 

    //Get view (resourceday, week, month)
    var view = $('#calendar').fullCalendar('getView');
    console.log(view.getResources); 

}
```

[Tux.fi has a solution for this problem](http://tux.fi/~jarnok/fullcalendar-resourceviews/)
His plugin returns the resource id on this way (see below that page)

```
When using external events, you can get resource data this way:
drop: function(date, allDay, ev, ui, resource) {
    var resourceId = resource.id; // this is resource id
    var resourceName = resource.name // this is resource name

    //YEAH!
}
```

But I need to have a vertical view! This are the only two plugins for fullcalendar being somewhat up to date. Some others are about 3 years old. I've contacted the programmers of these plugins to ask for their help but did not yet receive answer and I hoped SO could provide me with some help about this topic.

little note:
It is for a serious school project

I hope someone can help me fix one of these problems that leads to the solution.

**THIS IS FIXED BY A NEW UPDATE 09-04-2014 SEE ACCEPTED ANSWER**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've updated the fork to pass the resource information back on the event.data object.  See https://github.com/seankenny/fullcalendar/blob/v2/tests/droppable_resourceView.html for a demo.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Mr. Kenny, your link is broken.